# How to insert text after changing cell value in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to insert the current date at the end of the text when the user changes the cell selection. For example, the user types "Test" in any cell, and when they press Enter or change the selection to another cell, the text changes to "Test 01/19/2024".

I tried following in module Workbook_SheetSelectionChange but Excel repeats the action endlessly as changes are always occurring in the spreadsheet:

```
Range(Target.Address(rowabsolute, columsAbsolute)).Value = Range(Target.Address(rowabsolute, columsAbsolute)).Value & Date
```

Comment: You need to set `Application.EnableEvents = False` before changing the cell text (and set back to `True` when done)

Comment: I'd say you should use `Worksheet_Change` and then only `Target.Value = Target.Value & Date`. And you should also add some code to make it a bit more _bulletproof_ like `Application.EnableEvents = False`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    With Target
        If .CountLarge = 1 Then ' Users change a cell
            If Len(.Value) > 0 Then .Value = .Value & Date
        Else
            Dim c As Range
            For Each c In .Cells ' Users change multiple cells
                If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then c.Value = c.Value & Date
            Next
        End If
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```